# iOS 8 UISplitViewController details view resizing incorrectly when rotating to landscape and overlay visible

Tags: ios8, rotation, uisplitviewcontroller

Got another issue with UISplitViewContoller on iOS 8.

When in portrait, and the displayMode is UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryOverlay, when you rotate to landscape the secondary view controller's view doesn't resize correctly during the rotation animation. Once the rotation is done, the size is adjusted to fit the screen space and it snaps into place which is quite jarring.

However, if the display mode is UISplitViewControllerDisplayModePrimaryHidden when the rotation occurs, the secondary view's size is adjusted during the rotation animation and everything looks and works as expected.

This occurs even with the out of the box Master-Detail template project from Xcode 6.1.

Any thoughts on how to get the secondary controller's view to size correctly during the animation when the primary overlay is visible?